# iOS programmatically UI setting, NSLayoutConstraint report issue, but cannot find it

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout

This issue bother me many days. and I cannot understand why it happen.

Everything of UI is done programmatically. This view init and layoutSubview define the UI, and add it.

The Labels are designed to be put on the left side, and the ImageView is put on the right. all the padding and inter-space are 2.

**Here's my code:**

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    println("In Cell init!")

    viewsDictionary = ["title":title,"subDescription":subDescription,"image":imageView]

    if(autolayoutSet == false) {
    self.title = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.title.numberOfLines = 1
    self.title.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.subDescription = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.subDescription.numberOfLines = 0
    self.subDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    nailImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)

    self.contentView.addSubview(title)
    self.contentView.addSubview(subDescription)
    self.contentView.addSubview(nailImage)

    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    println("In Cell layoutSubView!")

        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds

        self.title.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin, self.titleWidth, self.titleHeight)
        self.subDescription.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, (topMargin+self.titleHeight+interMargin), self.subDescriptionWidth, self.subDescriptionHeight)
        self.nailImage.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width - ImageWidth - rightMargin), topMargin, ImageWidth, ImageWidth)

        println("Title \(self.title.text) cell layoutSubViewcounter \(self.layoutSubViewcounter)")
        layoutSubViewcounter++
}

func updateCellConstraints() -> CGFloat 
  {
              self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    title_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2)

    subDesc_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subDescription, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2)
    image_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nailImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2)
    image_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nailImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2.0)

    subDesc_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subDescription, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2.0)

     title_width_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: titleWidth)
     desc_width_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subDescription, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: subDescriptionWidth)
     image_width_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nailImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: ImageWidth)
     image_height_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nailImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: ImageWidth)

    self.contentView.addConstraint(title_constraint_H!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(subDesc_constraint_H!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(subDesc_constraint_V!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(image_constraint_H!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(image_constraint_V!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(title_width_constraint!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(desc_width_constraint!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(image_width_constraint!)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(image_height_constraint!)
}
```

**Test result report issue:**

```
2015-04-27 17:24:21.120 Swift_UI_programmatically[25239:5577543] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c24b6df0 H:|-(2)-[UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff8c24ac020 )",
    "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c24b39d0 H:[UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...'(220)]",
    "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c2783d70 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...'.midX == + 107.75"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c24b6df0 H:|-(2)-[UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff8c24ac020 )

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in UIKit/UIView.h may also be helpful.
2015-04-27 17:24:21.121 Swift_UI_programmatically[25239:5577543] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c24b39d0 H:[UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...'(220)]",
    "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff8c2783f10 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7ff8c24b9830'It is a well known fact t...'(211.5)]"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies in your Autoresizing mask. You have aligned the label to left side of content view with fixed width and also given NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint which is assigning horizontal center of label to 107.75.

Try setting property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO for UILabel and other elements inside cell.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Many thanks, after set all the UILable MaskIntoConstraints as No, it works perfectly.